# A single word for “blind” and “slow on the uptake”

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, american-english, slang, translation

We have a word *tiomny* in Russian which has the meanings *blind*, *dim*, and *dumb*. Is there a word (possibly slang) in American English which is as close in meaning to both *blind* and *slow on the uptake*?

Comment: I'm going to closevote as Not Constructive. There are any number of words that have more or less the required ***meaning***, and it seems utterly pointless to look for one (or more) that just happen to include all three of OP's metaphorical allusions, as opposed to other figuratively-referenced attributes (such as *dense, thick, slow,* etc.).

Comment: I don't see any reason to close my question. May you please provide me with the words with the required meaning instead?! I really need it! I don't think that the words like "dense", "thick" or "slow" have any close relation to "blind". These words seem to me rather like synonyms for "idiot", "dolt" or something. I do need word that renders "blind" in a sense of "inability to see further than the end of nose".

Comment: @ezpresso: I think "slow on the uptake" is exactly what we would say in English to intimate all of those qualities. Did you want something else because you thought "SOTU" wasn't what you needed?

Comment: @ezpresso: You say "tiomny" has the meanings *blind, dim, dumb*. I don't know Russian, so I don't know if maybe you're just citing those particular words because in English they're commonly used ***metaphorically*** in respect of people with below-average intellects or powers of observation. Or perhaps that's not important to you, I don't know. But I now see from your comment to tchrist that you apparently also like the idea of words which connote ***wilful*** refusal to understand, as opposed to (or *in addition to?*) simply lacking the mental capacity. It's all just too vague for me.

Comment: @tylerharms, Well, I would like something that is way more short and with more sense of irony.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, yes, exactly! The word "tiomny" in Russian does actually contain irony. It has strong connotations of such meanings as "ignorant", "unenlightened", kinda "doltish" and, yes, "wilful refusal to understand"! Also it is typically used to describe someone who seems not to be "in the know".

Comment: @ezpresso: I'm still not with you. Are you saying "tiomny" ***only*** means "doltish"? My point is that the primary meanings of *blind, dim, dumb* (sightless, faint, speechless) are ***metaphorically*** extended to the *uncomprehending, stupid* sense(s). Surely you can see from the size of the list offered by tchrist (and the absence of any other answers saying *"**This** is the one and only word you seek"*) that your question is too imprecise. Apparently you now want an "ironic" component too, but you still haven't edited your actual question text to reflect *any* of these additional factors.

Comment: *Тёмный* means "dark". In the figurative sense "dim-witted" it is not really used outside of a handful of idiomatic collocations. And in the meaning "blind" it is hopelessly archaic — it isn't in any dictionary I checked, and I've never heard anyone use it that way. When people hear of a movie titled *Тёмный рыцарь*, they don't take it to mean "The Dumb Knight", much less "The Blind Knight". In short, you cherry-pick weak or non-existent connotations of a word that has a strong literal meaning. Reproducing all that nuance in English, 1:1, in a single word, is simply impossible.

Comment: It sounds like the word you're looking for is "shortsighted." It's a valid medical term for needing lenses to see things far away, and as a shortsighted/nearsighted person, I can say it's certainly not offensive to apply in the figurative sense. "Myopic" is also used in this way but may be obscure to some.

Comment: Beware the old sense of *dumb*, as in *deaf-mutes*, who can neither hear not speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that comes slightly to mind might be a reference to the old cartoon character, [Mr. Magoo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Magoo).

[image: Mr Magoo shot from WP]

Otherwise, you will have to resort to some more general term for someone who is um, “subclueful”.  Such terms are almost infinite in number, for many are coined daily to supplement those that come down to us from Shakespeare and before.

Since you’ve asked for slang, I can give you a starting list.  Including both nouns and adjectives, and ranging from fairly fanciful to unspeakably vulgar, such a list might include words such as:

> airhead, ass, asshole, asswipe, astigmatic, babe, barbarian, bastard,
>   batarded, bear, birdbrain, bitch, blind, blindakins, blind ass, blindered,
>   blockhead, bonehead, boob, bore, brute, buffoon, cad, careless, child,
>   chump, churl, clod, clodpate, clown, credulous, cretin, dick, dickhead,
>   dickwad, dickweek, dillrod, dillweed, dimwit, dipshit, dodo, dolt, doof,
>   doofus, dookie, dope, dork, douche, douchebag, dufus, dumb, dumbass,
>   dumbbell, dumbfuck, dumb ox, dumdum, dummy, dunce, dunderhead, dupe, dweeb,
>   easy mark, fag, fair game, fathead, fool, foolish, fuckhead, fucktard,
>   geek, goon, goose, greenhorn, gull, gullible, halfsighted, halfwit,
>   headlong, idiot, ignoramus, ill-advised, ill-considered, illiterate,
>   imbecile, imperceptive, impolitic, impractical, improvident, imprudent,
>   ingénue, ingenuous, injudicious, innocent, jackass, jerk, lamebrain,
>   lightweight, loon, loser, lout, lunkhead, meathead, moron, Mr Magoo,
>   myopic, naïf, naïve, nearsighted, nerd, nimrod, nincompoop, ninny, nitwit,
>   noob, numbnuts, numskull, oaf, peasant, philistine, presbyopic, prick,
>   rash, retard, retarded, rube, sap, schlemiel, schmuck, shithead,
>   shortsighted, silly, simple soul, simpleton, spaz, stooge, stupid, sucker,
>   tard, tarded, tool, trusting soul, turkey, twerp, twit, twitterpated, unsagacious, unwary, victim, vulgarian, yoyo.

There is also a lot of variation in whether some of those compounds are written with or without spaces, or with or without hyphens.

**Be warned** that these vary in register from the recondite to the extremely coarse, and in contemporaneity from the outdated to the extremely recent, with plenty of nonce words to boot.  So I would never recommend any of them to a non-native speaker without knowing a great deal more about the exact context in which they planned to use them.  Otherwise you could very easily get yourself into extremely hot water.

For that matter, even Mr. Magoo is a cultural reference many will not get, and is quite possible offensive to blind people.

This is treacherous ice you’re trying to walk on here.  Be very careful.  Whatever you do, check with more than one native speaker to verify your choice.

Comment: I know your list is composed of *nouns*, whereas OP seems to be asking for an *adjective*, but I do think it's striking that none of the first three figurative usages that occurred to me *(dense, thick, slow*, as opposed to OP's *blind, dim, dumb)* contribute to any of the entries in your (non-exhaustive!) list. It just goes to show Anglophones can be very creative when we want to disparage someone's mental ability/agility/acuity!

Comment: Thanks! Mr. Magoo is very close to what I am really searching for. I like that "blind" (in a case of Mr. Magoo) is used in a sense of "stubborn refusal to admit the problem" (as stated in a Wikipedia article).

Comment: We're not worthy!  Your list is beyond awesome, tchrist, but I take exception to the "shithead" entry. It doesn't really fill the bill.  "shit-for-brains", on the other hand, would be more suitable. ;-)